# can't create javadoc with custom annotation file (cannot execute binary file)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, javadoc, archlinux

I'm new to eclipse and java and our university has given us a custom annotationsdoclet file but I can't create a javadoc. When I do I get this error:

`/home/simon/eclipse-workspace/Worms/resources/AnnotationsDoclets.jar: /home/simon/eclipse-workspace/Worms/resources/AnnotationsDoclets.jar: cannot execute binary file`

I think it might have something to do with what I choose as "javadoc command"(the first box when creating a new javadoc since I didn't get any instruction on what that should be and I went with the annotations file. I'm using arch linux and I think that's why I have to select this manually. I made the jar file executable but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to put the javadoc executable from my java SDK in the javadoc command box.